# Helm ls: Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:tiller"

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is helm broken, I keep getting:

```
Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:tiller" cannot list resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

when `helm ls`

Comment: Have you set up the service account and role bindings correctly? https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md#example-service-account-with-cluster-admin-role

Comment: Thanks, I was sure I had it right: now I created a yaml so it wont happen again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`helm` is probably fine.

You need to have correct serveice-account and role binding. Refer https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md#tiller-and-role-based-access-control for common scenario examples.

Answer (score 5):

The link shared on above answer are No more valid and throws a 404 error.
For completeness and users looking for solution sharing the fix steps below

**If below ERROR is reported on helm** :

```
$ helm list
Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

**SOLUTION**: Use below commands to create serviceaccount and clusterrolebinding  and patch the tiller-deployment to user service account.

```
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller

kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'
```