# Forbidden User Error on all Helm commands. How to give user access to Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I can't run any helm command without an error saying my user is forbidden. My user is forbidden to the kube-system and the default namespace.

Running something like this: `kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller`
 results in this error:

`Error from server (Forbidden): serviceaccounts is forbidden: User "{my-user}" cannot create resource "serviceaccounts" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"`

Running this: `kubectl get serviceaccount [-n kube-system]` results in this error:

`Error from server (Forbidden): serviceaccounts "[-n" is forbidden: User "cn188854" cannot get resource "serviceaccounts" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
Error from server (Forbidden): serviceaccounts "kube-system]" is forbidden: User "cn188854" cannot get resource "serviceaccounts" in API group "" in the namespace "default"`

Running this: `helm list` results in this error:

`Error: pods is forbidden: User "{my-user}" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"`

I'm guessing my user doesn't have access to the kube-system namespace, but I wouldn't see why not and I don't know how to give myself access to that namespace. I've reviewed several other posts and questions (such as [this one on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457589/helm-ls-error-configmaps-is-forbidden-user-systemserviceaccountkube-system) and [this one on github](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5100)). But I can't attempt any of their solutions because I always get a forbidden user on the helm command.

I'd appreciate any help, and would really appreciate some explanations as to why my user wouldn't have access at all like this.

Comment: How about using Helm 3?

Comment: Which namespace is tiller deployed in? And do you not have access to any of the namespace or just these? Are you able to manage resources in other namespaces using kubectl?

Comment: `Tiller` was deprecated in `Helm 3`. Did you try to install helm using official docs https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/#from-script ? Do you must use Helm v2?

Comment: After a lot of research and asking around, I've discovered that my user literally doesn't have access to the default or the kube-system namespaces in the cluster. I have to specify the cluster in which I have access. (This is a group cluster that is set-up this way for security.)Thank you for all your input.

Comment: @ineedtoknow could you post as an answer your solution? How did you specify access to cluster. It might help other users with similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research and asking around, I've discovered that my user literally doesn't have access to the default or the `kube-system namespaces` in the cluster. I have to specify the cluster in which I have access.
Access depends on how the cluster you are using is set-up. (My group cluster was set-up this way for security.)

So if anyone else is experiencing this problem, check what cluster you're using and what permissions you have. If you need to specify the `namespace`, like I do, you can add this argument to your command: `-n={name-of-namespace-you're-using}`

For example, I can't run `kubectl get pods` because I don't have access to the `default namespace`. But if I specify a `namespace` I do have access to, like this: `kubectl get pods -n={name-of-namespace}`, then I'll be able to see my pods.

Sometimes you might also need to specify the `tiller`, usually with by adding an argument like this: `--tiller-namespace={name-of-tiller}` Make sure to check the options for the commands on [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-commands), or on the [kubectl doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands) so you'll know what arguments to use.

Comment: Just for additional information. On Helm 3 `tiller` was deprecated.